# Handling a missed task with a recurring deadline

Tags: website-design, notification, alerts

I'm designing a user interface for a website that allows the user to set deadlines for certain tasks. Some of these tasks can be recurring in a variety of ways (Once per week, once a day, every Monday and Friday until a specific future date, etc). How can I handle deadlines that are skipped? For example, if a user wants to perform a task every Monday, on the next Monday should the website act as if the first deadline didn't exist? In most cases, but perhaps not all, once the next deadline rolls around it's too late to perform the first task.

Comment: Hey, can you ask the doubt in order? Difficult to understand the context. Can you put a few initial screens you have prepared?

Answer (score 1):

The task can be recurring, but the deadline can vary. The nature of the task will control the deadline timeline also. Assuming each task including its recurrence requires the same time, there are different ways to go about the pending task. E.g Having a separate page for pending tasks, or having a list views where you show the status of each recurring task, pending task should be filterable from here. You should notify the user whatever he has missed if it is an actionable sort or has some impact